# Opening CDR files in Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, coreldraw

Is there any free software that I could open a .CDR (CorelDraw) file in Mac OS X?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doesn't look like any free Vector Graphics software handles it directly.

Try using [UniCovertor](http://sourceforge.net/projects/uniconvertor/) and then opening it in [Inkscape](http://www.inkscape.org/)

Comment: Inkscape doesn't work in Snow Leopard as we can see in https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/398957 , and UniConvertor is not so UserFriendly. But I'll keep trying

Comment: Inkscape now has a snow leopard version. I've installed Uniconvertor, but now I get this error:   File "/Library/Python/2.6/site-packages/uniconvertor/app/__init__.py", line 103, in _import_PIL
    warn.warn(warn.USER, "Can't import the Python Imaging Library")